# How to prevent tooltip from showing when dialog is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have to following scenario:

There are several dialogs (some static, some created with ajax-loaded content, some created after pageload) on my site.

One as an example:

```
$(".agreementcount_dialog").dialog({
    position: {
        my: "center center",
        at: "center center"
    },
    draggable: true,
    resizable: true,
    modal: false,
    width: 250,
    height: 300,
    close: function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
});
```

And the jQuery-UI `tooltip` is included:

```
$('#main').tooltip();
```

Everytime when a dialog is opened, the tooltip is triggerd through the `autofocus` laying on the close-button of the dialog.

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/gexopelezo/1/edit?html,js,output)**

So now my Question:
How can I prevent the tooltip from showing when a dialog is opened ?

Can I set an option in the initialisation of the tooltip, **so the tooltip is not triggered when the focus is set on the close-button** ? This would be the best solution, because I have only one place where the tooltip is called and where I have to change someting.
**In fact, I don't want the focus to be changed but the tooltip not to be shown.**

I know it can be done with the `:tabbale` or the `autofocus` attributes, but is there another way? I don't want to edit all the dialogs among the project to add an new autofocus-element (**and then the dialog can't be closed by pressing enter or escape after opening anymore**) and I want to keep the functionalty of the tooltip in the dialogs.

**Note: Not every dialog is opened within a click-event.**

Comment: Downvoting without leaving a comment ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an easy solution to cope with my problem:

```
$('body').tooltip({ 
    items: ":not(.ui-dialog-titlebar-close)" 
});
```

This will exclude the close-buttons from the dialog from the tooltip-functionality, without affecting the autofocus.

Now there is no tooltip for the close-button, but the rest is not affected.

This can be extended easily and work with ajax-generated content.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: may it help

```
$('.open').on('click', function(){
   $('.dialog').dialog('open');
   $(this).focus();
});
```

Comment: This would be working, but the functionallty to close the dialog on enter or on escape after it is opening is getting lost.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to init tooltip after opening the dialog, it solves the problem, but i'm not sure this is the best way to do it.

Anyway, here's the demo. http://jsfiddle.net/utj47ty9/1/

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   $('.dialog').dialog({autoOpen: false});
   $('.open').on('click', function(){
     $('.dialog').dialog('open');
     $('body').tooltip();
 });

 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this would not work for me because I need the tooltip even if there is no dialog opend before.